# Convert list of nested object to list of flat object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following nested object:

I would like to convert this object to flat object, like this:

```
//just example of code for nested object
var someObj = new List<NestedClass1>
                {
                    new NestedClass1
                    {
                        prop1 = "",
                        prop2 = "",
                        prop3 = new List<NestedClass2>
                        {
                            new NestedClass2
                            {
                                prop4 = "",
                                prop5 = new List<NestedClass3>
                                {
                                    new NestedClass3
                                    {
                                        prop6 = "",
                                        prop7 = 0,
                                        prop8 = 0,                                        
                                    },
                                    new NestedClass3
                                    {
                                        prop6 = "",
                                        prop7 = 0,
                                        prop8 = 0,                                        
                                    },
                                }
                            },
                            new NestedClass2
                            {
                                prop4 = "",
                                prop5 = new List<NestedClass3>
                                {
                                    new NestedClass3
                                    {
                                        prop6 = "",
                                        prop7 = 0,
                                        prop8 = 0,                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

The result object:

```
var someResultObj = new List<FlatClass>{
    new FlatClass{
        prop1 = "",
        prop2 = "",
        prop4 = "",
        prop6 = "",
        prop7 = 0,
        prop8 = 0,
    }
}
```

Do you know any ways to do it use reflection or something else?

I wouldn't like use loop and initialize my flat object from this loop and 3d party libs.

I would like to do it flexible, is it possoble?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could just assign it, item by item, but I suspect it isn't always like that and your question is incomplete. You also don't say what happens to fields that have the same name. And if you do want it to work on any kind of object what are the criteria for descending into a child object? And if you have looked at Reflection, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
var result = new List<CombinedClass>();

foreach (var item1 in someObj)      
   foreach (var item2 in item1.prop3)
      foreach (var item3 in item2.prop5)
         result.Add(
            new CombinedClass()
               {
                  prop1 = item1.prop1,
                  prop2 = item1.prop2,
                  prop4 = item2.prop4,
                  prop6 = item3.prop6,
                  prop7 = item3.prop7,
                  prop8 = item3.prop8,
               });
```

**Given**

```
internal class CombinedClass
{
   public string prop6 { get; set; }

   public int prop7 { get; set; }

   public int prop8 { get; set; }

   public string prop4 { get; set; }

   public string prop1 { get; set; }

   public string prop2 { get; set; }

}
```